# Creating Python dictionaries based on a condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create dictionaries that will be order requests for a portfolio of funds. The dictionaries will be exported as JSON files, just to give a bit of context. This is what the dictionaries look like.

```
{
"accountID":"02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5.1452548617456",
"accountNo":"DWTE000005",
"userID":"02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5",
"accountType":2,
"ordType":"1",
"side":"B",
"instrumentID":"06926627-e950-48f3-9c53-b679f61120ec",
"orderQty":1.4312,
"comment":""
}
```

The condition that the dictionaries will be created upon are if the target weightings are above 0, as follows.

```
targetportfolio = {
'VXUS' : 0.2,
'GOVT' : 0,
'IVW' : 0.2,
'EEM' : 0.2,
'JNK' : 0,
'VDE' : 0.15,
'LQD' : 0,
'IJR' : 0.1,
'BIL' : 0,
'AAXJ' : 0.15
}
```

Where each fund (for example VXUS) will have an order generated if the amount in the target portfolio dict is greater than 0. I was thinking of something along the lines of the code below, but I am quite confused. Any ideas?

```
   def ordergen(portfolio):
   for i in portfolio:
    {
    "accountID" : "02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5.1452548617456",
    "accountNo" : "DWTE000005",
    "userID" : "02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5",
    "accountType" : 2,
    "ordType" : "1",
    "side" : "B",
    "instrumentID" :fundID[i],
    "orderQty" : ,
    "comment":""
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
targetPortfolio = {
'VXUS' : 0.2,
'GOVT' : 0,
'IVW' : 0.2,
'EEM' : 0.2,
'JNK' : 0,
'VDE' : 0.15,
'LQD' : 0,
'IJR' : 0.1,
'BIL' : 0,
'AAXJ' : 0.15
}

orders = []

for k in targetPortfolio.keys():
    if targetPortfolio[k] > 0:
        orders.append({
            "accountID" : "02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5.1452548617456",
            "accountNo" : "DWTE000005",
            "userID" : "02e57c7d-d071-4c63-b491-1194a9939ea5",
            "accountType" : 2,
            "ordType" : "1",
            "side" : "B",
            "instrumentID" : "",
            "orderQty" : "",
            "comment":""
        })

print(orders)
```

`.keys()` is your friend. You can now use 'k' to fill in your order details under the condition that their weight is above 0.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I'm also importing other dictionaries from other scripts, and I think that just by using sample[k] in dictionary after orders.append works.